# What is the difference between <button> and <input type="button"> in HTML? How do you use them property?

Tags: html, button

I am confused about the two types of buttons. In most cases, I think they are interchangeable. If they are not, how can I choose the proper one when coding?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure these two buttons are different.

- The `button` HTML element represents a clickable button, used to submit forms or anywhere in a document for accessible, standard button functionality. By default, HTML buttons are presented in a style resembling the platform the user agent runs on, but you can change buttons’ appearance with CSS.
- `input` elements of type button are rendered as simple push buttons, which can be programmed to control custom functionality anywhere on a webpage as required when assigned an event handler function (typically for the click event).

You can find some details in these links

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button